# javascript Como darle otra propiedad a una clase?

Tags: javascript, poo, javascript-objeto

Como puede recibir la clase Bookstore las propiedades de los demas libros?
Esto es lo que tengo

```js
// Bookstore class 
class Bookstore{
  constructor(name){
      
  }
 
}
// Book class 
class Book {
  constructor (name,quantity){
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    
  }
}
```

[image: Define the classes]

Comment: En ese enunciado no te están diciendo que `Bookstore` reciba las propiedades de los demás libros. Te están pidiendo que tenga una propiedad (un atributo) `books` donde se puedan almacenar los libros de la librería. Suena a una estructura de datos que permita guardar múltiples elementos `Book` ;)

Comment: Probablemente la propidad en la primer clase debe ser un objeto en la cual puedas almacenar N libros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto ☺

```js
// Bookstore class 
class Bookstore{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.books = [];
  }
  pickBook(pickName){
    let a = false;
    let b = false;
    let finalBook;
    this.books.forEach((book, index) => {
      if(book.name === pickName){
        if(this.books[index].quantity>0){
          this.books[index].quantity--;
           finalBook = this.books[index];
           a = true;
        }
        else {
          b = true;
        }
      }
    });
    if(a){
      return finalBook;
    } else if (b) {
      return "Not available";
    } else {
      return "Book not found";
    }
  }
  storeBook(book){
    this.books.push(book);
  }
  showBooks(){
    console.log(this.books);
  }
}
// Book class 
class Book {
  constructor(name, quantity){
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
  changeName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
  }
}
function aaa (){
  return 1;
}
let newBookstore = new Bookstore('Joss\'s Bookstore');
let testBook1 = new Book('Jack and the cuckoo-clock heart', 1);
let testBook2 = new Book('Foundation', 0);
newBookstore.storeBook(testBook1);
let book = newBookstore.pickBook('Jack and the cuckoo-clock heart');
console.log(book);
console.log(newBookstore.books);
```